# Passenger Kills Background Workers for Delayed Job

Tags: nginx, passenger, delayed-job, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am running Rails 4.2 on a Linux virtual machine. I am using Nginx as my web server and Passenger as my web application server.

My app runs without any issues. Recently, I started using Delayed Job to send out emails. This works fine, but the problem is my background worker processes are being killed for whatever reason, so emails are not being sent out when they should. After I SSH into my server, I run the following command to start a background worker:

```
rake jobs:work &
```

This fires off a background process and detaches the `rake` command from the terminal instance, so I would expect that process to keep running. The process appears to be killed by Passenger, as my background tasks won't execute after a few minutes.

How can I stop Passenger from killing my background tasks?

Comment: In the spirit of Gaming.SE's  [tradition](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4999/how-can-i-tell-if-a-corpse-is-safe-to-eat) [of](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24345/how-can-i-kill-adorable-animals) [alarming](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37805/my-head-keeps-falling-off-what-can-i-do) [titles](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21261/is-it-dangerous-to-go-extreme-pig-riding-in-a-thunderstorm), I hope this makes it to Hot Network Questions.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to make the title less alarming? I actually needed to have an answer in two hours, so you could say it was an alarming situation, but fortunately I figured it out!

Comment: Oh, I think the title is fine - it just sounds funny out of context, like the ones on Gaming (they try to do it on purpose).

Comment: Haha okay, thank you! I took a look at the questions you linked from Gaming SE - hilarious!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! I decided to run the `delayed_job` process instead. When running `rake jobs:work &`, it started a Ruby process, which Passenger kills off. Passenger doesn't seem to kill off other processes, though.

Following the [Delayed Job documentation](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#user-content-running-jobs), I added the following to my `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'daemons'
```

Then I ran the following in my virtual machine:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job start
```

I received a permissions error at first, so the script didn't run. To get past this, I set the `delayed_job` script to have full read/write/execute permissions:

```
chmod +x bin/delayed_job
```

I went away for about 10 minutes and came back, and the process was still running and sending out emails!